# How to download sat file with angular and C#

Tags: c#, angularjs, file, download, sat

I have been uploaded and saved files under **wwwroot** folder. But I can only download files like **aa.docx, aa.xlsx, aa.csv**,... but I can not download file like **aa.sat**.

My route link like: `192.x.x.x/SAT/aa.sat`.

Any one have an idea

Comment: What is a "sat file", exactly?

Comment: Your web-server is probably configured not to serve file-extensions it doesn't recognize (IIS is like this). What webserver are you using?

Comment: As @Dai points out, many web servers will only expose files they are configured to allow. Try downloading a `.config` file sometime

Comment: I am using IIS server. SAT files, which stand for "Standard ACIS Text," are stored in an ASCII text format. @Dai

Comment: What mean .config file are you suggested ?. Please tell me detail of it. Tks @Flydog57

Comment: I was just pointing out that standard config files (like web.config) are present in every .NET application but cannot be seen from a web client. Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/configure-request-filtering-in-iis

Comment: Tks for your suggest. I have been resolved the problems. Only need add mime types on IIS or configure function at start.cs. @Flydog57